# Animate startAngle in UIBezierPath in UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, uibezierpath, cabasicanimation

I have a UIView subclass, which draws an arc inside its frame. The draw method looks like this:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let clockwise = true
        let center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        let radius: CGFloat = rect.width / 2
        self.trackWidth = min(max(trackWidth, 1), radius)
        arc = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                          radius: radius - (trackWidth / 2),
                                          startAngle: startAngle!,
                                          endAngle: endAngle!,
                                          clockwise: clockwise)
        arc!.lineWidth = trackWidth
        arc!.lineCapStyle = .round
        self.color.setStroke()
        arc!.stroke()

        return
    }
```

This code was pulled from another SO'flow post, but it works fine and I'm using it to draw static arcs in an interface.

My question is, how can I animate the arcs, and specifically the startAngle of the UIBezierPath? I gather so far that this cannot be done with a regular UIView animation, so CABasicAnimation seems to be the go-to. But I can't figure out how to specify the property to be animated in a block of code like this:

```
    func animateArc() {
        CATransaction.begin()
        var arc = arcs.first!
        DemoView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
            arc.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "startAngle")
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = DemoView.radianizer(40)
        animation.autoreverses = false
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        
        arc.layer.add(animation, forKey: "startAngle")
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
```

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Your goal is not quite clear... do you want to animate the drawing of an arc, so, for example, it starts as a "dot" at 12 o'clock and animates to an arc from 12 to 3 o'clock? Or, do you want to start with an arc from 12 to 3, and animate it around to 6 to 9?

Comment: @DonMag Clearly it is the former, right? If it were the latter, OP surely would not have asked to "*specifically*" animate the start angle, but the end angle as well.

Comment: Sweeper is correct: the arc starts off swept through 270 degrees, and over time, reduces to zero...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than drawing the path in `draw`, you can use a layer-based approach. Add a `CAShapeLayer` as a sublayer of your view.

```
let arcLayer = CAShapeLayer()
arcLayer.path = yourFullArc
arcLayer.strokeColor = self.color.cgColor
arcLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
arcLayer.lineWidth = trackWidth
arcLayer.lineCap = .round
self.layer.addSublayer(arcLayer)
```

Then this sublayer's `strokeStart` can be animated, which is kind of like animating the start angle. The value of `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` ranges from 0 to 1, and they basically mean "which part of the line do you want to be stroked". Now you can convert the "from" and "to" values 0 and 40 to values for `strokeStart`.

The layer can then be animated like this:

```
// calculating values for strokeStart
let angleRange = endAngle! - startAngle!
let from = startAngle! / angleRange
let to = (startAngle! + DemoView.radianizer(40)) / angleRange

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
animation.fromValue = from
animation.toValue = to
animation.autoreverses = false
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
arcLayer.add(animation, forKey: "someAnimation")
```

Comment: Ah, that looks like a winner. Very late here in S.E. Asia, will be on this first thing in the AM....

Comment: what's the function of "someAnimation" in the last line?

Comment: @DanDonaldson It's just a key for the animation, like a name, so that you can use this name to refer to it if you want to remove it later.

Comment: oh that makes sense

Comment: Yep, it's a winner.

Comment: follow on question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71775613/identifying-which-cabasicanimation-has-stopped-with-delegate